# super in python 3, when class only has inherited function

Tags: python-3.x, super

Newbie question on `super()`: In the toy example below, I was surprised that the output is `C` and not `A` since `J` in inherits `foo` from `A`.  Here is the code:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        return 'A'


class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        return 'C'


class J(A):
    pass


class E(J, C):

    def f(self):
        return super().foo()

    def foo(self):
        return 'E'

print(E().f())
```

`J` inherits `foo` from `A`; the MRO of E is:

```
(<class '__main__.E'>, <class '__main__.J'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

so how come 'A' isn't the return value? ie evaluation proceeds to `C`

Comment: Doesnt looking at the mro answer your question? C comes before A.

Comment: Yes but `J` inherits from `A` so it should have a `foo` that returns `A` ... no?

Comment: That's not how mro works. One of the rule is that any class comes prior to it's superclass. Let me formalize this in an answer

Comment: That would be great, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python class inheritance call order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248527/python-class-inheritance-call-order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `super` does not just recover the superclass. It instantiate an object which recovers methods in the context of a given *method resolution order*. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49248796/5079316) features a reimplementation of `super` in Python to help you understand how it resolves a method inheritance.

So, as you can see, the *method resolution order* of your class is `(E, J, C, A, object)`. Since it comes up first, then `E` inherits `foo` from `C` and not `A`.

Now the question you are probably asking is...

### Why does `C` comes before `A`?

The [C3 linearization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) which builds the *mro* has the property that if some class `X` inherits from `Y`, then it will come prior to `Y` in the *mro*.

As you can see, this is respected in your example. The class `C` inherits from `A` and thus has to come first.

The following example demonstrates that as soon as you were to drop the `A` inheritance from `C`, then the result becomes the one you were mistakingly expecting.

```
class A:
    pass

class C: # Dropped A inheritance
    pass

class J(A):
    pass

class E(J, C):
    pass

E.__mro__ # (E, J, A, C, object)
```

Comment: ok -- i still don't understand why `J` which comes before `A` or `C` and inherits the `foo` from `A` isn't called.. ie the resolution goes to the first class in the MRO which is `J`.. `J` has a `foo` inherited from `A`... why isn't that the method being called?

Comment: Because super does not look at the class base, it looks at the class mro, let me add on this

Comment: @Alex have a look at the first paragraph. I linked an answer where I developped exactly on the question you are asking. I'm actually realizing this might be a duplicate.

Comment: OK let me take a look at that - appreciate the detailed response

Comment: I think I may have had a slight misunderstanding of inheritance in Python: when you write `class J(A)` the Python interpreter does not actually create a method in `J.foo` but rather creates a pointer to `A.foo`, thus super simply doesn't follow that pointer.. is that right?

Comment: It doesn't even do that. It resolves which method to call *when you get the attribute*. You can even [change your base dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/how-to-dynamically-change-base-class-of-instances-at-runtime) and it will change the method resolution, proof that no pointer is created. A class is only that: its own methods and its base to resolve inherited methods if a method is not found in the subclass.

Comment: By example, if you access `J.__dict__`, you will not find `foo`. Where to get `foo` from is resolved only when you try to access it, and there the mro comes into play.